# Xamarin System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build a project and this error came up:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\coded\.nuget\packages\xamarin.android.glide.disklrucache\4.12.0.4\buildTransitive\monoandroid10.0\..\..\jar\annotations.jar'.
File name: 'C:\Users\coded\.nuget\packages\xamarin.android.glide.disklrucache\4.12.0.4\buildTransitive\monoandroid10.0\..\..\jar\annotations.jar'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.SizeAndContentFileComparer.GetHashCode(FileInfo obj)
   at System.Linq.Set`1.InternalGetHashCode(TElement value)
   at System.Linq.Set`1.Find(TElement value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__64`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.DistinctFilesByContent(IEnumerable`1 filePaths)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries.RunTask()
   at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17  WoWonder
```

Please what should I do ?

Comment: Write a readable post to begin with would be nice.

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling `xamarin.android.glide.disklrucache` would be a good first step

Comment: Please Guide me how to uninstalling and reinstalling xamarin.android.glide.disklrucache

Comment: You can refer to the document about managing the nuget package in visual studio for mac. 
 They are similar. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/nuget-walkthrough?view=vsmac-2019)

Comment: it not working when un-install and re-install xamarin.android.glide.disklrucache

Comment: When I reference the package, it worked correctly. And then I try to change the target Android version to a low one such as Android 7.0. I meet the same error like you. So it is recommended to change the target Android version to the high version such as Android 9.0 in your application. The package tell users that it reference Android version 9.0 and 10.0 in its instructions. @HashCoded

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was trying to install Glide 4.12.0.4, I uninstalled the Glide (from the same NuGet Manager Window), then I chose to install an older version of Glide like 4.12.0.0, and worked like charm!

Comment: Reverting from 4.12.0.4 to 4.12.0.0 worked for me too.

Comment: have done as you said but not working out, still save error

Comment: can you share me the folder file, i think if can past the folder it may work C:\Users\xxxxx\.nuget\packages\xamarin.android.glide.disklrucache\4.12.0.4\buildTransitive\monoandroid10.0\..\..\jar\annotations.jar'